# A Strong Law of Large Numbers exercise

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots$ be i.i.d. random variables and $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define

$$Y_{n}=f(X_{n},X_{n+1},X_{n+2})$$

If $\mathbb{E}|Y_{1}|<\infty$, show that

$$\frac{Y_{1}+\cdots+Y_{n}}{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{E}Y_{1}\,a.s.$$

As the title suggests, I believe that this exercise will ultimately boil down to the SLN. However, while the random variables $Y_{n}$ are certainly identically distributed, I don't believe them to be independent. How should one think about this problem?

Comment: They are not independent, but you can split into $3$ sequences: $(Y_{3n}),(Y_{3n+1}),(Y_{3n+2})$. Each of these sequences contains independent random variables, so you can use the strong law. Then try to finish from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of  the sequences $(Y_1,Y_4,Y_7,\dots)$, $(Y_2,Y_5,Y_8,\dots)$ and  $(Y_3,Y_6,\dots)$ is iid. Apply SLN three times and add.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.